# add columns to pandas dataframes where values match another dataframes columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
A =
date,station_uuid,diesel,e5,e10,dieselchange,e5change,e10change
2019-05-01 00:01:07+02,00061511-4c4d-4444-8888-acdc00000001,1.289,1.469,1.439,0,1,0
```

and

```
B = 
uuid,name,brand,street,house_number,post_code,city,latitude,longitude
00060723-0001-4444-8888-acdc00000001,BAGeno Raiffeisen eG,freie tankstelle,Künzelsauer Strasse,7,74653,Ingelfingen ,49.296821594238,9.6613845825195
```

Where `B` contains a row for each `uuid` of `A`.

I want to add columns of `B` to `A` where the `uuid` has the same value.

So for example I want to add `brand` and `city` to `A` for matching `uuids`

**EDIT**: Basically `B` is a detailed description of `uuid` of `A` and i want to merge the two datasets, to have all feature columns of `B` in `A`

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple command:

```
A = pd.merge(A, B['brand','city'], how='left',
                                   left_on='station_uuid', right_on='uuid')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
a = pd.merge(a, b[['uuid', 'brand', 'city']], how='left',
         left_on='station_uuid', right_on='uuid').drop(labels=['uuid'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is a good way to do this, however if you want to keep the index and order of dataframe A, you can use following:

```
A[['brand', 'city']] = B.set_index(['uuid'])[['brand', 'city']].reindex(A['station_uuid'])
```

and this only works when there's no duplicated value in the column `uuid`.